# Django custom template tags: 'str' object has no attribute 'notification_set'

Tags: django, django-templates

While defining a custom template tag that acts on the top level base.html (not the app-level base) I am running an issue with a query that executes just fine on the shell.

For example,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(pk=3)
u.notification_set.filter(viewed=False).count() # returns 1 as expected
```

However, in the template tag this gives me the strange error

```
AttributeError at /mynotes/

'str' object has no attribute 'notification_set'
```

`.` is where I have my manage.py and here is the custom template tag:

./app/templatetags/mytags.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name="unread")
def get_unread(user):
    return user.notification_set.filter(viewed=False).count()
```

./templates/base.html

```
{% load mytags %}
...
{% unread request.user%}
```

EDIT: ./app/models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    notification_for_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

Comment: Can you show the `models.py` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Changed

```
{% unread request.user %}
```

to

```
{% unread user%}
```

and it works. +10 for anyone to explain this error.

Comment: Did you add `django.core.context_processors.request` into `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings?

Comment: @anhtran no i didn't. In the app level templates I didn't have to use it because I guess that context is automatically passed by a view, whereas in the case of base.html, there was no view. Thanks.